# If $A$ is positive and invertible, and $B$ is Hermitian, then $A+iB$ is invertible.

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

Exercise 14(b) from SEC. 82 of *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces* - 2nd Ed, from Paul R. Halmos.

Prove or disprove: if (operator) $A$ is positive and invertible and if (operator) $B$ is Hermitian, then $A+iB$ is invertible.

(The dimension for the underlying unitary space is not specified as finite or infinite.)

My solution requirement: if the assertion is to be established in finite dimensional spaces alone, then I request a proof in finite dimensions together with a counterexample in infinite dimensions. Else, if the assertion is to be proved in both types of spaces, then I request a proof in infinite dimensions. Else, if the assertion is to be shown as invalid in both types of spaces, then I would appreciate a counterexample in finite dimensions.

---

First edit:

My original (and scatterbrained) attempts in the finite dimensions were around showing that $A+iB$ is normal, and that it does not have $0$ as an Eigenvalue, thereby invertible. Once successful, the next hope was to extend the argument to infinite dimensions.

(PS: the trouble with my original approach was pointed out on this network after me posting the problem. Thereafter, I posted the second edit as follows.)

---

Second edit:

I am able to establish the finite-dimensional case in a relatively straightforward manner. Proof: in finite-dimensions, towards showing that $A+iB$ is invertible for the given $A$ and $B$, it is sufficient to show that $(A+iB)x = 0 \implies x = 0$. If $(A+iB)x = 0$ for some $x$, then $Ax = -iBx$. It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
(Ax, x) &= (-iBx, x) = (x, iB^*x) = (x, iBx) = (x, -Ax) = -(A^*x, x) \\
&= -(Ax, x)\\ 
&\implies (Ax, x) = 0 \implies (\sqrt A \sqrt Ax, x) = 0 \\
&\implies (\sqrt Ax, {\sqrt A}^*x) = 0 \implies (\sqrt Ax, \sqrt Ax) = 0 \implies \Vert \sqrt Ax \Vert^2 = 0 \\
&\implies \sqrt Ax = 0 \implies \sqrt A \sqrt Ax = 0 \implies Ax = 0 \\
&\implies x = 0
\end{align}
$$ since $A$ is invertible. In summary, $(A+iB)x = 0 \implies x = 0$. Thus, $A+iB$ is invertible. This proof exploits the finite-dimensional assumption on two occasions: firstly the invertibility criteria for $A+iB$, and secondly the theory of positive square-roots for positive transformations. Both exploitations aren't readily extendable to the infinite-dimensional case in my understanding. Would appreciate some pointers.

(Credits: the above argument was developed after I was rightly pointed out on this network that my earlier approach was misguided. Specifically, I was advised that $A+iB$ was not normal, and that the normality wasn't needed anyway.)

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $A + iB$ is normal. For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$

Comment: The operator $A+iB$ is normal if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: If all eugenvalues are non-zero, a matrix is invertible. You do not need the assumption that the matrix is normal. In the infinite dim case, are you sure you listed all conditdions?

Comment: Yes, I have stated the problem statement as it is.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Although it is not explicitly specified, I suspect (given the title of the book) that we are meant to assume that the space is finite dimensional.

One approach is as follows. First, note that $A$ has a positive square root, and $A + iB$ is invertible iff the matrix
$$
A^{-1/2}(A + iB)A^{-1/2} = I + i(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})
$$
is invertible.  We note that $M = A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ is necessarily Hermitian.

Now, suppose for the purpose of contradiction that the equation $(I + iM)x = 0$ has a solution $x \neq 0$ and proceed.

---

Alternatively, we could note that
$$
\langle (I + iM)x, (I + iM )x\rangle = \\
\langle x,x \rangle + \langle Mx, Mx \rangle + 2 \operatorname{Re}(\langle x, iMx \rangle) =\\
\|x\|^2 + \|Mx\|^2.
$$

Comment: Nice. But isn't this approach suitable only in finite dimensions? In my understanding, the theory of positive square-roots for positive transformations works only in finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @RajPanse Yes, but as I state in my answer I strongly suspect that you are only meant to deal with the finite dimensional case.

Comment: Can we have a counterexample for the infinite-dimensional case if the assertion doesn't hold there? Would like to add my observation that the book (as mentioned in its preface) is not limited to the finite-dimensional considerations alone, and has plenty of results and exercises for the infinite-dimensional spaces. The author has been quite careful to specify the space as finite-dimensional whenever required, else it is assumed to be the general (infinite-dimensional) case. E.g., in the preceding exercise 14(a), the author has specified the space to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: @Raj Interesting. I don't know of such an example off the top of my head, but I suspect that a counterexample exists within the realm of unbounded operators, depending on how one defines "invertible" in that context.

Answer (score 3):

@Omnomnomnom' answer can be adapted to work on general Hilbert spaces.

$A$ is positive and invertible and hence has an invertible square root $A^{1/2}$. Therefore
$$A+iB \,\text{ is invertible} \iff A^{-1/2}(A + iB)A^{-1/2} = I + i(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})\,\text{ is invertible}.$$

Moreover, $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ is hermitian so its spectrum is contained in $\Bbb{R}$. Therefore

$$\sigma(I + i(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})) = 1 + i\sigma(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}) \subseteq 1+i\Bbb{R}$$

so certainly $0 \notin \sigma(I + i(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}))$ and hence $A+iB$ is invertible.

Comment: Nice. Can we have a counterexample in the more general infinite-dimensional case (outside the Hilbert space setting) if the assertion isn't valid there? Have just modified the question to request a proof or a counterexample in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: @RajPanse I think this also works for general inner product spaces. The only tricky point is the existence of the invertible square root $A^{1/2}$ but it seems this can be argued by considering the unique extension $\overline{A}$ of $A$ on the completion of your space (which is a Hilbert space). Hence $\overline{A}$ has an invertible square root $\overline{A}^{1/2}$. Its restriction on the original space is the square root $A^{1/2}$ of $A$. Moreover, since $\overline{A}^{1/2}$ is invertible it is bounded from below so $A^{1/2}$ is also bounded from below and hence invertible.

Comment: I guess you assume that the underlying inner product space is complete, i.e., it is a Hilbert space. That's not given in the question. So, I think that we need either a proof for the case of a general, infinite-dimensional space, or a counterexample in that space. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @RajPanse Yes, in the answer I assumed that it is complete. In the comment above I tried to argue in the case of an general (perhaps incomplete) inner product space by considering its completion. However, I'm not sure that this works, namely maybe there is a problem with invertibility of $A^{1/2}$.